# Button doesn't work, apparently it's not defined

Tags: javascript, function, button

The problem is mentioned in the title. The code is below:

Error messages:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: obwod is not defined
> at HTMLInputElement.onclick line 15

> Uncaught ReferenceError: pole is not defined
> at HTMLInputElement.onclick line 16

```js
    
function obliczanie (pro,ok)
{
  this.promien=pro;
  this.y=ok
  this.daneWyjscie-function(){
    return this.promien+" "+this.y+";
  }
}
function oblicz(input1){
  return 1 * input1
}
function pole(){
  var O2 = pole();
  O2.promien=input1;
  O2.y=oblicz( Math.PI * (promien * promien));
  document.getElementById('wynik').innerHTML= "obwod jest rowny: "+ y.toFixed(2)
  return y.toFixed(2);
}
function obwod(){
  var x=Number(document.getElementById("dlugosc").value);
  var z=Number(document.getElementById("szerokosc").value);
  var y=oblicz(2*x)+(2*z);
  document.getElementById('wynik').innerHTML= "obwod jest rowny: "+ y.toFixed(2);
  return y.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>he</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Prostokąt</h1>
    Wpisz a   <input id="input1" type="text" value="1" /><br />
    <br>
    Wpisz b   <input id="input2" type="text" value="1" /><br />
    <br>

    <input type="button" name="obwod" value="obwod" Onclick="obwod()">
    <input type="button" name="pole" value="pole" Onclick="pole()">
    <p id="wynik">Wynik: </p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not related to the errors, but `var O2 = pole();` as a first row in `pole` function causes an infinite loop. Related to errors, when you remove the extra quote, there's no type errors in the provided snippet, instead you'll get a Maximum stack size exceeded error beacuse of the above mentioned infinite loop.

Comment: Or actually there is still a type error, the text inputs have different ids than with which you refer them in the script. Assuming this only being in the post, though.

Comment: Thank you! I am fully aware about the text inputs and I've already fixed them. I'm still struggling with those two errors (buttons still do not work).

Comment: We can't help you, if you won't provide an example code with which we could reproduce your issue. The only advices we can give are that you've to check your code for syntax errors, if there's a single syntax error, the execution of that script is stopped, and anything after the syntax error doesn't get defined. Also check that the referred names match. If the script is coming from a separate JS file, you've to check that it is really loaded at the time you click a button.

Comment: First thing I would do is put `console.log(x, y, z)` before `document.getElementById` and see that does it print out in the browser console. Continuing from there you'll be able to figure it out. Powodzenia!

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your code.

```
return this.promien+" "+this.y+";
```

There's an empty unclosed string at the end of that return statement. Does something belong there or should it just be this:

```
return this.promien+" "+this.y;
```

Comment: that fixed the `obwod is not defined` error

Comment: Thank you! But there's still a little problem. The button doesn't seem to work despite including your fix. Unfortunately, the same type of error is still existing.